# Shellscript to run in subdirectories

Tags: windows, powershell

Below code will run in "`c:\test`" directory only , i want this code to run in all subdirectories of "`c:\test`".  used -recursive but no help.

```
cd c:\Test
$Afiles = ls -r *.bak 
$Bfiles = ls -r *.7z

$Alist = @()
$Blist = @()

foreach( $A in $Afiles) {
    $Alist += $A.BaseName 
}

foreach( $B in $Bfiles) {
    $Blist += $B.BaseName 
}

foreach($A in $Alist) {
    if($Blist -contains $a) 
    {
        rm ("$A.bak") 
    } 
}
```

Comment: So are you looking for all 7z files that have a .bak with a matching name regarless of its full path in c:\test and remove them?

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell (2.0) resolves this short-hand command:

```
ls -r *.bak
```

to

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path *.bak
```

Since the `*.bak` items are all files, there is nothing to recurse through

What you want is **`-Filter *.bak`**, not **`-Path *.bak`**

Use explicit parameter names if you want to avoid this sort of surprise. You can also grab the `BaseName` property directly from the output of `Get-ChildItem`:

```
cd c:\Test
$Alist = Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD -Filter *.bak -Recurse | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName
$Blist = Get-ChildItem -Path $PWD -Filter *.7z -Recurse  | Select -ExpandProperty BaseName

foreach($A in $Alist) {
    if($Blist -contains $A) 
    {
        Remove-Item "$A.bak" 
    } 
}
```